# Multicast server receive the same data it sends

Tags: java, networking, udp, multicast

I'm trying to allow clients that connect to my UDP server to send packets to the server, I have a server running so packets can be sent to the clients, but trying to send packets back via the client to the server seems to create some weird errors.

If I start the server, then open a client, the client will receive the first packet from the server, the client then tries to send the packet to the server, this is received by the server, but then the client throws this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "testing"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Pong.PongUDPClient.main(PongUDPClient.java:71)
```

Line 71 will be pointed at in the code
The server console is just printing out the data it should be sending to the client,

Here is the whole code for the server

```
package Pong;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

//This is the actual server
public class PongUDPServerThread extends Thread {

//speed to send data
private long dataSpeed = 10;
private int port = 4447;
private int idPlayer = 0;
private PongModel model;
private PongView  view;
private PongPlayerThread players[] = new PongPlayerThread[2];
private MulticastSocket socket = null;
private InetAddress group;
private DatagramPacket packet = null;
private int ID = 1;

public PongUDPServerThread() throws IOException 
{
    super("PongUDPServerThread");
}

public String rtnInfo()
{
    String str;
    str = model.getBall().getX() + ":" +
          model.getBall().getY() + ":" +
          model.getBats()[0].getX() + ":" +
          model.getBats()[0].getY() + ":" +
          model.getBats()[1].getX() + ":" +
          model.getBats()[1].getY();
    return str;
}

public void setupPong() throws IOException 
{
    System.out.println("Pong");
    model = new PongModel();
    view  = new PongView();
            new PongController( model, view );

    model.addObserver( view );       // Add observer to the model

    //view.setVisible(true);           // Display Screen
    model.makeActiveObject();        // Start play
    //start server
    socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    socket.joinGroup(group);
    //socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    //Inform server user
    System.out.println("Server is running");
}

public void run()
{
    //Server loop
    while(true)
    {

        //Receive the data
        try
        {
        byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[256];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuf, receiveBuf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

        System.out.println(received);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }


        try
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            //Gather data
            buf = rtnInfo().getBytes();
            //System.out.println(buf.toString());

            //Send data
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1"), port);
            socket.send(packet);

            //Sleep the server
            try
            {
                sleep((long)dataSpeed);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //socket.close();

}

}
```

Here is the client code

```
package Pong;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PongUDPClient {

private static int port = 4447;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    //Setup pong rdy
    PongModel model = new PongModel();
    PongView  view  = new PongView();
                      new PongController( model, view );

    model.addObserver( view );       // Add observer to the model

    String pos;

    model.makeActiveObject();        // Start play
    //model.clientModel();

    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
    //socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1");
    //Join the UDP list port
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    socket.joinGroup(address);

    DatagramPacket packet;
    view.setVisible(true);           // Display Screen

    System.out.println("Connected");
    //Id is sent here.

    while(true)
    {

        //Send data to server
        try
        {
            byte[] receiveBuf = new byte[256];

            //Gather data
            receiveBuf = "testing".getBytes();
            //System.out.println(buf.toString());

            //Send data
            packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuf, receiveBuf.length, InetAddress.getByName("230.0.0.1"), port);
            socket.send(packet);

            //Sleep the server
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        String  received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
        //System.out.println("Server data: " + received);

        String[] posValues = received.split(":");

        model.getBall().setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[0])); // <-- Line 71
        model.getBall().setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[1]));
        model.getBats()[0].setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[2]));
        model.getBats()[0].setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[3]));
        model.getBats()[1].setX(Double.parseDouble(posValues[4]));
        model.getBats()[1].setY(Double.parseDouble(posValues[5]));

        //Check for keyboard input

        if(PongController.moveUp == true && PongController.moveDown == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Up");
            PongController.moveUp = false;
        }
        else if(PongController.moveUp == false && PongController.moveDown == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Down");
            PongController.moveDown = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //serverOut.println("nothing");
        }


    }
}

}
```

Been stuck on this for awhile, and can't seem to find any tutorials on how to send packets from client to server using Multicast.

Comment: First, either check the characters in the string (0-9,.- etc) before handing it to parseDouble, or catch the exception parseDouble throws.

Comment: For debug purpose, print the packets being sent to client using `SOP` at server side.

Comment: Can I not just get rid of Multicast socket and just use a DatagramSocket instead? All i want is data to be sent using UDP and data to be send by the client also.

Comment: Is it one to one connection ?

Comment: Nope, the server allows for multiple clients to connect

Comment: And for every message sent by Server there will be a reply from each client??

Comment: The purpose of multicasting is much different than what you're trying to accomplish.  Therefore, yes, get rid of the multicast socket and have your clients send to a single UDP socket the server listens on.

Comment: So just use DatagramSocket then :)

Comment: Yup. At the least send data back to the server with a DatagramSocket.

Comment: I mean as in the server will not use Multicast anymore, just DatagramSocket

Comment: That's probably the best choice (No multicast).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing multicast loopback. Turn it off with `MulticastSocket#setLoopbackMode(true)`, or, if that peer is just sending to the multicast group, not receiving, it doesn't need to join the group at all.